# how to implement windows 7/vista window flip on windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, directx

I have try using DirectX to capture and rotate output,
but the output effect is static,
not like in windows 7 win+tab.

Comment: What is "Window flip"? And do you want to do this programmatically or manually? I don't understand

Comment: @Pekka: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Flip-3D. It's basically a 3D version of ALT-TAB.

Comment: I think he is referring to the Windows Aero theme in Vista / 7. Using then Win Key + Tab results in a graphical 'aero' version of the classic Alt + Tab application switch.

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 7, leaving XP won't kill you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about making it so that the windows in the "Flip" mode dynamically update as the applications redraw, then what you ask for is not possible in Windows XP.

Applications on Windows XP draw directly onto the screen, while applications on Windows Vista/7 draw on a compositing engine called Aero (if it is enabled). Since Aero captures all graphical output from the applications, it is able to update the preview windows in Windows Flip.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have not personally tested it, but there is a software called WinFlip.
Once you download and run that exe file, the windows flip (windows+tab) should work like in windows 7 or vista

http://winflip.stylekings.de/